# wso2 identity server policy editor engine getInstance() returns java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Iam using WSO2 identity server version 5.4.0. I need to customize "standard policy editor" dynamically. I know I can do it utilizing UI (PAP->Policy Administration->Add New Entitlement Policy->Standard Policy Editor->You can do it from here), but I need to do it using java since I am trying many different combinations (like adding random attributes under different supported categories, adding new supported categories etc).

I have made a lot of search about that, but I have just reached out blog posts for doing it from the management console. For now, I am trying the following code snippet for getting the content of policy editor:

```
PolicyEditorDataHolder policyEditorData = PolicyEditorEngine.getInstance().getPolicyEditorData(EntitlementConstants.PolicyEditor.STANDARD);
Map<String, String> attributeIdMap = policyEditorData.getAttributeIdMap();

for (String att:attributeIdMap.values())
{
    System.out.println("Attribute: "+att);
}
```

But I am getting null pointer exception from getCarbonHome() method so I cannot get instance of PolicyEditorEngine:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.common.PolicyEditorEngine.getInstance(PolicyEditorEngine.java:59)
    at Main.findAttributes(Main.java:688)
    at Main.main(Main.java:179)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459)
    at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Properties.java:166)
    at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:796)
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.CarbonUtils.getCarbonHome(CarbonUtils.java:253)
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.CarbonUtils.getCarbonConfigDirPath(CarbonUtils.java:300)
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.CarbonUtils.getEtcCarbonConfigDirPath(CarbonUtils.java:287)
    at org.wso2.carbon.context.CarbonContext.getOSGiServicesConfigFilePath(CarbonContext.java:395)
    at org.wso2.carbon.context.CarbonContext.<clinit>(CarbonContext.java:77)
    ... 3 more
```

Could you please help me to get the instance of PolicyEditorEngine and retrieve/edit the content of standard policy editor?

Thank you!

Comment: You can get rid of the NPE related to carbon home by setting the system property "carbon.home" to point to the root directory of Identity Server. However, I have few questions related to the approach you are taking. Can you explain a bit more on why you need to do this customization and how you are trying to achieve it (more technical info on this please)

Comment: @farasath Actually, I have thought about setting system property "carbon.home" before, but when I inspect the getCarbonHome() method of Carbon.Utils class, I see that it is set. Or would you suggest me to configure carbon home directory in some configuration file in the IS_HOME\\repository\conf?  I need this for series of experiments on wso2 is, for my research. For now, unfortunately I'm trying to do this manually using management console, so no technical details :(